# django template: get dictionary value

Tags: django, templates

My view function does the following:

```
search_parameters = {"words": "hello"}
return render('mypage.html', {'results': results, 'search_parameters':search_parameters})
```

In my template, I thought I could get "hello" by writing:

```
{{search_parameters.words}}
```

but it's blank.

What does work is looping through every value like so

```
{% for key,value in search_parameters.items %}
```

but I'd really like to avoid doing that every time I need to get a value from the dictionary.

Comment: `{{search_parameters.words}}` would work. There's something else wrong.

Comment: Are you using `render` correctly? According to docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render), the first required parameter is request which you do not pass. Maybe you meant to use `render_to_response`?

Comment: {{search_parameters.words}} did magically work once my computer and I had a good nights sleep. (I actually used render_to_response, not render)

Answer (score 1):

Like miki725 have pointed out, you're missing the request arg

```
search_parameters = {"words": "hello"}
return render( request, 'mypage.html', {'results': results, 'search_parameters':search_parameters} )
```

then you could do {{ search_parameters.words }} as you wish